# Apple Watch App - Mix approach of Page based application and Hierarchical application

Tags: ios, objective-c, watchkit, apple-watch, watchos-2

Is there any way to add horizontal scrolling/pages inside Hierarchical WatchKit App.  OR navigate to controllers inside Page-based application.  (Hybrid approach of hierarchical and page based application)

I want to show screens in horizontal paging, however use can navigate inside further screens/controllers from any page.

As we can not push any controller in page based application, nor we can show horizontal pages in hierarchical WatchKit app. Is there any way to use hybrid approach?

My target is to show horizontal paging to user at start of application and user can navigate into hierarchy of any page.

P.S: I've implemented hierarchical and page-based applications separately, looking for some hybrid solution.  One option is to make page-based application, and present a hierarchical interface modally. but there is limitation that i can not navigate further. (let's assume there are 10 pages, and in each page user can navigate upto 3 levels hierarchy)

Any suggestion would be appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

According to WWDC 2015 Session Videos, it is not good to make such a hybrid interface.

Imagine you have a hierarchical one with two buttons. Clicking on first button opens up a view containing Page-based navigation. This will work, but if you want to scroll between pages from this page to previous one, this gesture is like returning back to Hierarchical view (scrolling from left side), so we will have a disorganization here.

In other hand, if you include buttons in a Page view controller, then user will expect to return to the only first page when returning back all the way. When he returns back to the first page, again he may thinks I must return again and so there will be another disorganization here between returning back all the way and scrolling toward the page.

If you need to implement this feature in your app, you can make a Page View navigation by dragging views to each other while pressing control key, and then add buttons. Control-drag buttons to the destination view controllers, or you can implement a hierarchical one and then control-drag the destinations together.

See WWDC 2015 session videos to get more about that. They can be found in [developer.apple.com/wwdc](http://developer.apple.com/wwdc).